# Android Setting Up the Search Interface tutorial

Tags: android, search

Im reading the first part of this tutorial to add a global search on an android app but I don't get this part.

http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

> To display the SearchView in the action bar, inflate the XML menu
>   resource (res/menu/options_menu.xml) in the onCreateOptionsMenu()
>   method of your activity:

I't doesn't describe how to "inflate the XML resource" in the tutorial and im not sure where else in the documentation thats at. Does anyone know which file to inject that code into thats below the paragraph above...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and if you need search view in action bar , your menu xml should be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:appname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_holo_light"
    android:title="@string/action_search_title"
    appname:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    appname:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Comment: do you know a good beginner resource? I don't know how to edit / open the activity or where to add the xml file. The tutorial in the android dev does not describe which files to edit, only the concepts. Do you know where in the android doc / resource that explains editing / adding activity

Comment: Read "Adding an Action View" in the link

Comment: im getting "R cannot be resolved to a variable" now when I run it. I checked online but no links will work for me to resolve the error. I'll keep looking, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I got a blank project working and was able to add both code. I added to MainActivity.java and added options_menu.xml in the res/menu folder and put <item inside. Now the app will run on my device but it will automatically crash when it opens? Also I have one error -> MenuInflater cannot be resolved to a type